# max RAM in 32 bit machine

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I am aware of possible duplicate questions already in stackoverflow. But those questions do not address my question directly. My understanding is that 32 bit machine uses 32 bit to store  memory addresses, therefore, the maximum memory it can have is 2^32 bit. However, 2^32 bit = 2^29 byte = 2^29/10^9 = 0.5 Gigabyte.

I know that the answer should be 4 gigabyte. But I simply cannot figure out where is my mistake. HELP!

Comment: 2^32 is addressable *bytes*, not bits. Also, 1024b = 1KiB, 1024KiB = 1MiB, 1024MiB = 1GiB (using decimal K/M/G will throw off the math slightly as well although, in a twist of fate, it's used by manufacturers to report [spindle] HDD size) ..

Comment: A 32 bit machine with 32 bit address registers can address 2^32 bytes, as an address selects all bits of a byte.

Comment: @user2246674 thanks for your quick reply. but how to understand the relationship between 32 bit and 2^32 addressable bytes then? I am just a bit confused here.

Comment: There are 2^32 *bytes* means 2^32*8 *bits* (or 2^35 *bits*); but modern computers generally can only reference memory directly with a resolution of bytes (there are bit operations that can be performed on bytes, but a bit within a particular byte is not directly accessed).

Comment: @user2246674 i can completely understand your argument if the machine is called 32 byte machine. however, they are called 32 bit. that still confuses me.

Comment: It may help to think about the bytes as addresses.  You can identify 2^32 addresses with 32 bits. You specify the address you want to read or write using your 32 bits, then you go and load or store that address.  In most 32 bit machines (which use 32 bits to address memory locations) each addressable memory location contains 1 byte.

Comment: @Dr.Tower Thank you for your answer! I understand it now. Could you put it in the answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the 2^32 refers to the number of addressable bytes not the total number of bits in memory.  you can address 4 billion bytes ( 32 billion bits) or 4 gigs of memory.  For instance

```
Address 0 | Address 1 |... | Address 2^32
........................................

8 bits    | 8 bits    | ...| 8 bits
```

EDIT:
The 32 bit machine usually refers to the number of bits you can stuff into the CPU's registers (not RAM).  Thus 1 register allows for 32 bits which can address 2^32 bytes of RAM.

EDIT:
Here is a good explanation on superuser:
https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems